# Issue with get shortcut function not loading in separate script

Tags: function, shell, powershell

So I have the following script I am trying to run which keeps erroring out

```
    . .\stshortcut.ps1 | 
    Get-Shortcut . |
    Where Target -eq "cmd.exe" |
    %{$myPath, $myNewName = $null;
    Write-Warning "Processing $($_.Link)";
    If (-Not (Test-Path .\BadShortcuts -PathType Container)) {New-Item -                                         
    WhatIf -ItemType Directory BadShortcuts | Out-Null};
    [string]$myPath = $_.Arguments.Split()[-1] -replace '"';  
    [string]$myNewName = $_.Link -replace "\.lnk$";
    Rename-Item -WhatIf -Force -Path $myPath -NewName $myNewName;
    (Get-Item -Force $myNewName).Attributes = '';
    Move-Item -WhatIf $_.LinkPath .\BadShortcuts;}`
```

the error I get is as follows

```
    The term 'Get-Shortcut' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,   
    function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
    name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
    again.
    At C:\Shared\APPS\FixShortcutX2.ps1:1 Char 13
    + Get Shortcut <<<<< . |
         + CategoryInfor          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Shortcut:String)[],   
         CommandNotFoundException  
         + FullyQualifiedErrorID : CommandNotFoundException
```

the stshortcut.ps1 script has the get-shortcut and set-shortcut functions and are called to do such - I got this script from

https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4su2jg/zeroday_malware_renamed_folders_on_a_shared_drive/
which is an answer script to fix a macro virus from a word doc attachment - sent from a spoofed email address -

Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated

*EDITx2* after some further helpful advice and editing I now am receiving the following

**Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript' . Cannot convert the "Target" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At C:\Shared\Apps\FixShortcutX2.ps1:3 char:6
+ Where <<<<< Target -eq "cmd.exe" |
    +CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand**

Comment: Forgot to state where I got the stshortcut script data from - came from here
http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/7895.aspx

Comment: change `.\stshortcut.ps1 |` to `. .\stshortcut.ps1`

Comment: Thank you Mathias - the error still appears the same way

Answer (score 0):

You need to dot-source `stshortcut.ps1` before you can use `Get-Shortcut`.

Change the first line:

```
.\stshortcut.ps1 |
```

To

```
. .\stshortcut.ps1
```

Comment: I performed this action - and still get the error that the Get-Shortcut is not recognized as the name of cmdlet, etc, etc

Comment: If `stshortcut.ps1` is located in the same folder and has the exact contents as the ones you link to, the above should work

Comment: stshortcut.ps1 contains these functions

Comment: it contains the functions for get-shortcut and set-shortcut

Comment: An empty pipe element is not allowed

At C:\(path)\FixShortcutX2.ps1:4 Char:32
+ %{$myPath, $myNewName = $null;| <<<<
    +Category Info             : Parser Error: (:) [], ParseException
    +FullyQualifiedErrorID : EmptyPipeElement

Comment: @KaroiVulka that pipeline symbol is not in your original post.

Comment: fixed the error - had a problem with duplicate lines